# hide all child elements on multiple divs

Tags: jquery

I have four divs and want to hide all child elements on each of them.

```
$('#col1').children().hide();
$('#col2').children().hide();
$('#col3').children().hide();
$('#col4').children().hide();
```

I believe there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do all with only one line:

```
$('#col1, #col2, #col3, #col4').children().hide();
```

If you have only these divs you may reduce all to:

```
$('[id^="col"]').children().hide();
```

In this way all divs having an id starting with col will be selected.